# Is it possible to serve multiple endpoints by one Gcloud extensible server proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I cannot find information online about how to run multiple endpoints in Gcloud endpoints.

In the Gcloud endpoint example, it only describes how to set up an ESP that serves 1 endpoint, which I managed to get it to work

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: esp
    image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1
    args: [
      "-P", "9000",
      "-s", "SERVICE_NAME",
      "-v", "SERVICE_CONFIG_ID",
      "-a", "grpc://127.0.0.1:8000"
    ]
    ports:
      - containerPort: 9000
  - name: bookstore
    image: gcr.io/endpointsv2/python-grpc-bookstore-server:1
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8000
```

I have a container that opens 4 grpc endpoints.
I tried the following configuration: but it does not seem to work as expected.
      containers:

```
  - name: platform
    image: gcr.io/platform-100007/platform:latest
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8002
      - containerPort: 8005
      - containerPort: 8011
      - containerPort: 8008

  - name: esp
    image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1
    args: [
      "-P", "9005",
      "-a", "grpc://127.0.0.1:8005",
      "-P", "9002",
      "-a", "grpc://127.0.0.1:8002",
      "-P", "9011",
      "-a", "grpc://127.0.0.1:8011",
      "-P", "9008",
      "-a", "grpc://127.0.0.1:8008",
      "-s", "testgrpc.endpoints.platform-100007.cloud.goog",
      "-v", "2017-10-09r0",
    ]
    ports:
      - containerPort: 9005
      - containerPort: 9002
      - containerPort: 9011
      - containerPort: 9008
```

service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: platform
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:

    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9002
      nodePort: 30082
      name: "grpc"

    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9005
      nodePort: 30085
      name: "8005"

    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9011
      nodePort: 30811
      name: "8011"

    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9008
      nodePort: 30808
      name: "flow"

  selector:
    run: platform
```

When I read the [startup][1] options https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/specify-proxy-startup-options

e.g. `-P HTTP2_PORT --http2_port HTTP2_PORT Sets the ports to be exposed by the proxy for HTTP/2 connections.`

Since it is using `ports` here so I assume it must be a way to configure the proxy to serve multiple backend services, but I couldn't find any documentation about that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why you need to run your service in 4 different ports.   Even if you have multiple gRPC services, they all can run on the same port. If for load balancing, a container or pod is not the right place for load balancing.  You should create more pods.
Well,  ESP doesn't support such load balancing feature, doesn't support multiple endpoints.

BTW, here is the [source code](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-tools/blob/master/start_esp/start_esp.py) to setup ESP.